# OAuth consent screen - ability to remove application logo

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

I added an application logo by mistake on the OAuth consent screen (URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent), and now it says my consent screen requires verification by Google.

Is there any way to remove the application logo from the consent screen?

**Edit:**
I didn't make it clear before but I wanted to remove the logo to get rid of the verification notice.

Comment: Did you find anything out? I am in the same boat

Comment: This likely is the intended behavior; just await the review.

Comment: For what it's worth, for me, the easiest solution was to take a deep breath, then create another project with the same information, without adding a logo.

Comment: This is unbelievable!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In order to delete the logo, follow these steps:

- Open the OAuth Consent Screen Configuration in Chrome or a Chromium derivative. https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent
- Upload any image that differs from the one previously uploaded.
- Open your Developer Tools (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I).
- Open the Network tab.
- (Optional) Press the Clear button to make it easier to search later.
- Click the Save button on the website to upload the new logo.  (If the Save button is disabled, go through the full "Submit for Verification" process.)
- In the Network tab, look for a request similar to "123456789987?alt=json&key=...".
- Click on the entry and ensure that the Request Method is PUT.
- Right-Click the entry and select "Copy"->"Copy as cURL (bash)".
- Paste it into a text editor and search for the text `"iconUrl":"https://..."`.
- Change the text to read like the following: `"iconUrl":""`.
- Back on the site, open up a Cloud Console session (The terminal icon in the top menu bar) and paste the modified command, then run it.
- Verify that logo got removed from consent screen and verification status has changed.

Please keep in mind that this may require you to verify your app again.

Since June 11th of 2020 there's a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/158736319) open requesting the adition of a remove logo button to make this process easier. Please leave your comment, star the issue and leave a +1 if you are also affected by this issue.

Comment: I am trying to avoid verifying the app

Comment: I work in Cloud Platform Support and I am not aware of any method to undo google verification. At this point you can ignore the verification emails, after 3 emails they will stop insisting and the application will remain with the unverified tag, or you can proceed to verify it. The procedure is only to remove the logo

Comment: That's true, you should complete the change. Usually any change you made on the consent screen will required you to submit a new verification process, I would recommend to make the change and request G Suite API support to help you and see if there is a chance to speed up the process since the change was minimum.

Comment: This method worked for me. I set the `iconUrl` to an empty string and now no longer need verification.

Comment: I followed the instructions but I got error :"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value \"json^\" for query parameter 'alt'",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: petit
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 156
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: for
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 131   . I just removed the url inside the bracket...

Comment: Worked for me today, except I had no visible "cloud console". Running the curl command in a shell on my local machine worked.

Comment: This didn't work. Is this seriously the procedure for something that should just be a button on the console? This approval process is the worst.

Comment: Just tried this as well without success. This really must be one of the shittiest experiences I ever had as a developer...

Comment: For all you guys experiencing this issue, there is an [open feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/158736319) to solve this issue. If you feel so you can go by **star the issue and leave a comment** as you are also expecting this feature to be default

Comment: @Chris32 please, for your experience, how much time (days, weeks, months...) they take to solve this kind of issue? The procedure explained in the answer didn't work for me :(, I double checked the steps...

Comment: Well, since this is the introduction of a new feature i'm not even sure if they are going to implement this at all. This will depend on the ammount of users requesting this feature (go and star the PIT). Then this can take between some months (maybe 6 months?) and years. In any case don't count on having this tool anytime soon because is unlikely

Comment: This is no longer working. Google changed image implementation from icon URL to its Base64 encoding. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62414912/1992004

Comment: You may need to switch from console.developers.google.com to console.cloud.google.com to get to the cloud console.

Comment: As of August 2020 the issue is still present, but this solution no longer works because Google API requests have changed. It now sends base64-encoded image data within the request and replacing it with an empty value returns an error. (the same mentioned in the comments above)

Comment: Why Google. Why? Why such a pain!

Comment: This no longer works look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62414912/oauth-consent-screen-ability-to-remove-application-logo-old-solution-is-no-lo

Comment: Worked for me — thank you! But also: Lol. This feels like an appropriate place to drop this link: https://aws.amazon.com/

Comment: This has broken our setup. Would not recommend.

Answer (score 39):

**As of Jan 2023** (confirmed by hlustosa) icon can be removed with the following steps. Please note that if your project is not already in an organization you will be stuck at the step 8 unless you can add your project to an organization.

Since this is a combination of two answers above with additional steps I put all the steps here for clarity. Credits to @Chris32 and @ropsnou for the initial steps.

1. Remove all existing API keys and Client IDs from the [OAuth Credentials page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)
2. Open the [OAuth Consent Screen Configuration](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) in Chrome or a Chromium derivative.
3. Upload any image that differs from the one previously uploaded and click "Save and continue"
4. In the Network tab, look for a PUT request like this: [https://clientauthconfig.clients6.google.com/v1/brands/745625634622/icon?key={key}](https://clientauthconfig.clients6.google.com/v1/brands/745625634622/icon?key=%7Bkey%7D)
5. Right-Click the request and select "Copy"->"Copy as cURL (bash)".
6. Paste it into a text editor and do following changes

   - Remove `/icon` from the url
   - Change request method to `DELETE`
   - Remove `--data-raw` parameter and its long value
7. Activate Cloud Shell by clicking the terminal icon in the top-right corner of the [GCP website](https://console.cloud.google.com/). Paste and run the command you modified in the previous step. If you get `INVALID_ARGUMENT` error you probably still have an API key or Client ID associated with the consent screen (Check the Credentials tab on GCP). If you get `{}` the command was successful and the logo was removed. However, together with the logo a larger brand entity was also removed, and if you try to modify the consent screen you will get "An error saving your app has occurred."
8. To recreate the brand run the following command in the Cloud Shell (it assumes you have the correct project active):
   EDIT: The command may fail for two reasons (see comments for more info):

   - User is not owner of the email
   - Project is not in an organization

```bash
gcloud alpha iap oauth-brands create --application_title='<title>' --support_email='<email>'
```

9. Now the logo is gone and you can again modify the consent screen

Comment: Thanks! This is very well detailed information and functional.

Comment: Step 8 fails for me with an error: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.

Comment: Just a guess but maybe you have a typo in argument name or illegal characters in title or email value? Would help if you post the full command. Or Google has changed something again.

Comment: Step 8 also fails for me with INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument. I tried gcloud alpha iap oauth-brands create --application_title='myappname' --support_email='me@example.com' and even the same command with <title> and <email> left in.

Comment: Adam, please try the command with a real email address you own. According to the docs _"the user issuing the request must be an owner of the specified support email address."_ https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/programmatic-oauth-clients#setup-oauth

Comment: I can confirm that this works as of Sep-2021. If you are getting INVALID_ARGUMENT error, make sure to delete the client-ids on credential page and then follow step 8 before saving.

Comment: @Prakhar recreating the brand still gives me an INVALID_ARGUMENT error even though there are no client ids whatsoever have any idea what else might be causing this I'm stuck  with this for hours any help would be appreciated

Comment: @FadiBanna is the email address you are using in `--support_email` parameter at step 8 shown in the consent screen configuration"User support email" dropdown?

Comment: @SamuliAsmala yes it is

Comment: Step 8 seems to fail for me too with the same error message "INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument". Even "gcloud alpha iap oauth-brands list" gives the same error. Have this stopped working or i have missed something @SamuliAsmala??

Comment: I have done this and now I can´t use anything!!!!! I can´t add oAuth Client key!!! PLEASE DON´T DO THIS

Comment: You can migrate the recources from google cloud platform from "no organization" to a free organization indentity.  Then "gcloud alpha iap oauth-brands" commands will work.
See https://github.com/google/triggerator /Limitations: The instructions below must be run within a Google Cloud Organization by a member of that org.

Comment: @Victor, could it be that your project was not in organization and that was the reason for the failure?

Comment: Can confirm this worked as of Dec '21. The only thing I'd note is that in step 7 I was unclear what the Cloud Console session was. The icon to open this is on the actual webpage in the top-right corner.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and feedback. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: You saved my life thank you so so much

Comment: Thanks! It worked at Jan 25 2022. I had to remove all keys and credentials before.

Comment: What Network Tab? I don't see this no where

Comment: It's the Chrome developer tools' Network Tab. You can access developer tools with CTRL + SHIFT + I.

Comment: Confirming this still works as of May 2022.

Comment: Confirming this method still works: Aug 3, 2022
**Step 8 is critical"" - make sure these values are set before starting this procedure.

Comment: Also for Step 8, you need to ensure you have set the `core/project` property. Else you'll end up getting the following error:

"ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.iap.oauth-brands.create) Error parsing [project].
The [name] resource is not properly specified.
Failed to find attribute [project]. The attribute can be set in the following ways:
- provide the argument `--project` on the command line
- set the property `core/project`"

To do that run: `gcloud config set project <PROJECT-ID>`.

Comment: Still working Sep 12, 2022 :)  THANKS SO MUCH FOR THIS!!  The only way I manage to survive using Google products is through StackOverflow posts like this.

Comment: **This broke our OAuth app and we cannot make changes or add credentials.**

Comment: This does work if you follow all the steps correctly.
Be aware that when you copy the curl request from Chrome, it gives you two (one is compressed) and you have to delete the second one.

Comment: This worked for me. This man is out here doing God's work... Thank you!

Comment: What if I don't have any organization? My project belongs to "No organization" and `gcloud alpha iap oauth-brands create --application_title='<title>' --support_email='<email>'` returns error `INVALID_ARGUMENT: Project must belong to an organization.`

Comment: I confirm it worked for me (jan 2023). But be careful, for some reason, if your project does not belong to an organization, you will be stuck. I had to add mine to a new one to make it work at the end.  @SamuliAsmala could you warn people at the begining of your answer that they will be stuck at the step 8 if they are not able to add their project to an organization?

Comment: Good point @hlustosa, I added warning to the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

For those who were unable to update it using the 'PUT' method (as answered by @Chris32 )and are ready to delete the consent screen and create a new one, can simply replace 'PUT' with 'DELETE' and remove --data-binary section (as delete doesn't take any payload) and can run it using a regular bash shell.

Comment: I did this. The request returned 200. It took around 2 or 3 minutes for it to reflect on the UI.

Comment: Worked immediately. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexBenfica Do you only changed `PUT` to `DELETE` and removed `--data-binary` section? Doing this in my case request returned `"error": {"code": 400, "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" }`

Comment: If I remember well... that was all I did. But I might have removed any other parameter that does not make sense for a DELETE call.

Comment: Works! Thank you! What a terrible experience by google

Comment: also getting {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

Comment: This no longer works for me, I'm getting a 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

The methods above did not work for me, I kept getting INVALID_ARGUMENT. This is because I had client credentials in the project. I had to delete the client credentials and the DELETE request method (without data-binary) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the above solutions, and see that we no longer can send "DELETE" requests, as cURL sends `404` responses.

My solution is that I submitted my app for verification (you don't have to pay unless you request sensitive/restricted scopes, and even then, they will send you an email with a confirmation of pricing etc).

This allows you to use the consent screen as before, without the icon, but without verification. (When you're verified, they will let you use your icon).

Once a representative gets back, let them know you intend your app to be used internally, and you just want them to delete the image.

Comment: Always 404 error here with `DELETE` method as well, `PUT` doesn't work either :-(
No sensitive/restricted scope asked. OAuth consent screen still "needs verification" presumably because of the app icon.
Tried to submit for verification twice 3 days ago but still got no validation nor message from Google.
Creating a new app would mean losing all public reviews / usage stats :-(
Very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the requests method and it didn't work, and it put my project in a locked state where I couldn't edit it anymore.
If you're just starting with the Play Services and it isn't yet in production, the easiest is honestly to drop the project and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

**[UPDATE] - 2020**

Is still possibile to delete your previously uploaded logo through an API call, although it requires a little modification of the answer *Abhishek Srivastava* suggested.

You need to:

1. *"Copy as cURL (bash)"* as for the original answer
2. Replace the *PUT* method with *DELETE*
3. Do not remove the *--data-binary* section, instead clean it all up until it looks like this and nothing else: `--data-binary '{"brandId":"<your_brand_id>"}'`

This will remove your consent screen entirely,

Comment: also getting {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

Comment: You are probably sending the status also in the payload, double check your complete API call

Comment: @jasan I had the same issue. I solved removing the "OAuth 2.0. Client ID" (under Credentials section) before proceeding with the curl command

Comment: The DELETE call causes an ERROR 404 not found error

Answer (score 1):

May 2021 - It is still possible to completely delete the consent screen! The following changes are needed compared to the original instructions:

- remove /icon from the request URI. The updated URI should follow the format `https://clientauthconfig.clients6.google.com/v1/brands/{BRAND_ID}?key={KEY}`
- change request method from PUT to DELETE
- completely remove --data-binary or --data-raw part of the request

This will delete the entire consent screen (not just the icon), so that a new one can be created from scratch.

Comment: This method worked for me, but only after removing all API KEYS and Client-IDs associated with the project.

Comment: This didn't work correctly for me. I removed OAuth credentials associated with the project (there were no other keys/IDs for the project) and entered the shell command as specified. This cleared everything (including app name and logo) except Authorized domains and Developer contact information from the OAuth consent screen. It didn't delete the consent screen entirely. When I edit the consent screen, fill all required fields, and attempt to save and continue, I see, "An error saving your app has occurred." I guess I'll delete the project and start over.

Comment: Didn't work for me and I had the same experience as @Monyker. "An error saving your app has occurred." response paylod had a reason for failure: `RESOURCE_DELETED` and the resource name in question was `brand`.

Comment: Same here, messed up with the consent screen. I had to add the command `gcloud alpha iap oauth-brands create --application_title='<title>' --support_email='<email>'`

Answer (score 1):

**Just to be aware.**

You may not be able to use "Auth0 consent screen" again after the recommendations of the others post.

```
{"error":{"code":5,"message":"The resource has been deleted.","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo","reason":"RESOURCE_DELETED","domain":"clientauthconfig.googleapis.com","metadata":{"resource_name":"[\"brand\"]"}}]}}]
```

[image]

and if this happen, please use the follow command that @SamuliAsmala recomended.

```
gcloud alpha iap oauth-brands create --application_title="TITLE" --support_email="EMAIL"
```

Answer (score 1):

As of March 17, 2023, this functionality should finally be working according to [Buganizer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158736319#comment398)

> I'm happy to share that you are now able to remove your app logo from the OAuth consent screen configuration in Google Cloud Console. We know that this has been very frustrating for our developer community, and apologize for how long it has taken to give you this basic capability.

> Some details about the feature:

> - if your OAuth consent screen hasn't been verified, removing a logo takes effect instantly
>   if you have completed verification, you cannot immediately remove your existing logo, but you can replace it and submit for re-verification (this seems counterintuitive, but it's part of our efforts to protect your developer account from abuse)
> - if you are stuck in verification and want to back out, you can change the Publishing Status back to "testing" (but beware that you should only do this if your app is not live with users, otherwise it may affect their ability to sign in)

> - This is one of many features that we are now actively working on to improve the OAuth experience, so you spend less time on configuration and can focus on building apps that delight our shared users. Thanks for your patience, and for being part of the Google Developers community.

Answer (score 0):

From my research so far, there is no way to remove the application logo from the consent screen.

You don't have to submit the account for verification unless you are asking for a permission mandating a verification.

Comment: @Chris32 has posted an answer which works. Marking his answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the status of the app from "Published" to "Testing" in your "OAuth consent screen" and see if it works.

I was in a similar situation where I had uploaded a logo and was being asked to submit my app for verification. I did submit my app for verification but with incorrect data for website details etc. The Google reviewer for my project got back mentioning this seems to be a internal/personal use app and to convert my project status to testing instead of published. After doing this I think my logo got deleted automatically from my project. So the moment we upload the logo the project moves from testing to published status and since there is a logo uploaded it has to go through the verification process.

Here is the [mail](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rh0arfSOjpmZElkOJnjQonCV26CFqSjuEkGtGht4F3M/edit?usp=sharing) I received from Google with the info links intact.

Please Note: If you define your project as a testing project then you need to provide tester email ids for this project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, uploaded a logo image by mistake, but I don't see a problem here. I just went ahead and submitted for verification and a few hours later I received this email:

> Thanks for submitting a verification request.
>
> If your app doesn't need to display an icon, you can skip the
> verification process and no action is required. If you do skip the
> verification process, the existing functions of your app won't change,
> as long as the scopes used by your project don’t change.
>
> Otherwise, if you’d like to continue with the verification process:
>
> Make sure you’ve completed all the required steps. Reply directly to
> this email to let us know. The review process can take up to 6 weeks.
> Thanks for your patience during this period.

So just don't respond and don't finish the required steps and the verification process will stop automatically without affecting your app.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to complete the verification process and one of the requirements was that the developer privacy policy page or link contain the logo.   My plan was to use the policy for all my apps if I could so I added a transparent png file the right size and removed the logo off my development web site and verification for branding passed fine.  I did not know at the time that adding a simple logo triggered all these requirements; I just wanted oauth to work.  For me the oauth screen did not even pop up until Google had verified my app. [just a spinning progress bar]

Answer (score 0):

@Samuli Asmala's answer is correct. However, Step 8 will sometimes throw the following error:

```bash
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.iap.oauth-brands.create) Error parsing [project].
The [name] resource is not properly specified.
Failed to find attribute [project]. The attribute can be set in the following ways:
- provide the argument `--project` on the command line
- set the property `core/project`"
```

So to fix this run the following command:

```bash
$ gcloud config set project <PROJECT-ID>
```