# How can I remove an app from the OAuth consent screen in console.cloud.google

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

I tried to set up social login for my website but I accidently uploaded a logo to the OAuth consent screen, which has locked my app in a verification Status: Needs verification. I get the following message:
"Because you updated the application logo, your app registration requires verification by Google.   Please prepare your app to submit for verification".
I am unable to delete this application and set up a new one (without a logo) or remove the logo from the existing one. It's totally locked me up? I also get a message that it will only allow 100 logins before it stops. How can I get rid of this thing, I've got a banging headache, and spent 8 hours going around in circles... Should I just remove the google login from my website? Is that my only option now?
Please help me!

Comment: I believe that this question has been asked and answered. Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989198/oauth-consent-screen-ability-to-remove-application-logo) answery your inquiry?

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'll take a look. From what I can tell, the limit of 100 sign ups that shows up in the console, has not budged from zero, so I'm wondering if I just leave it alone and don't submit for verification, it will just stay as it is? I'm ok with that!

Comment: @Chris ANy solution worked or keeping as it is fine?

Comment: @VirRajpurohit Keeping it seemed to be fine. I no longer use it, but it worked without any trouble. The user numbers never moved in testing, so I'm guessing that the 100 limit would never be reached anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone facing this issue in 2021:

If you place a logo on Oauth consent screen by mistake, submit your app for verification. This will allow you to use the consent screen as before.
When you are contacted by a representative, inform them you want to use the app withouth the logo.

You can also follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989198/oauth-consent-screen-ability-to-remove-application-logo/) or add your **+1** in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/158736319).