# OAuth consent screen - ability to remove application logo: old solution is no longer working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-workspace

**Question**: how to remove an application logo.

**Solution**: previous solution from this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168008/1992004, is no longer working.

Google changed the format of `"iconUrl"` to `"icon"`, and uses now the `Base64`-encoded data stream, like `"icon":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...`, instead of the image URL, previously written as `"iconUrl":"https://..."`.

I've tried `"icon":""` and many Base64-encoded values like `"icon":"IA"`, `"icon":"Lw"`, and some of other - no success. I get console messages like

for `"icon":""`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The request failed because one of the field of the resource is invalid.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure",
        "violations": [
          {
            "type": "client_auth_config",
            "subject": "?error_code=9&error_field_name=UpdateIconRequest.icon&error_field_value=%3CByteString@3eeee81e+size%3D0+contents%3D%22%22%3E"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.identity.clientauthconfig.v1.ClientAuthConfigError",
        "code": "ICON_STORAGE_FAILURE"
      },
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.identity.clientauthconfig.v1.IconStorageError",
        "reason": "INVALID_IMAGE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value at 'icon' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed for \" \"",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "icon",
            "description": "Invalid value at 'icon' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed for \" \""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does somebody know, what should be inserted here to remove the logo image from the app?

Comment: What is the full request you make?

Comment: Absolutely identical to those recommended in the older thread: copied from the network tab XHR request, which is PUT and contains `?alt=json&key`, copy it as cURL for bash, edited its content -  the `icon`-part as described, and run it in the Cloud Shell.

Comment: Is your application internal? Is uploading a blank/transparent image not a suitable workaround? I don't think there's a supported way of removing a logo, at least one which is documented by Google.

Comment: yes, absolutely internal. blank image doesn't help - image remains and Google means, it should be validated.

Comment: For anybody encountering this issue, please star and leave a comment on their open issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158736319

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, there is no way for this to be done.*

#### More Information:

Once an OAuth Application Logo has been uploaded there isn't a supported way of removing it - in the question that you linked the way that this was done is a bit hacky, inspecting the network requests and building a new request from the previous JSON object sent via the UI really shows this.

As the icon URL has changed to need a Base-64 encoded value this has been deprecated. Whether this was intentional by Google or not is hard to say, but now an empty value will always return `INVALID_ARGUMENT`. Any data in the value for `icon` will also just replace the image data and so this isn't a viable workaround, as as far as the validation process goes, image data *exists* and so will need to be verified.

If it's not too much of a arduous process, the only workaround here is to create a new GCP project with a new OAuth consent screen without uploading an image. Of course, you will need to reactivate all the relevant APIs and link the relevant scripts and projects to the new set-up.

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important and that you would like to request they implement it. Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services. I would suggest using the feature request template for [G Suite Add-ons](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392207) as this is a component for which GCP Projects could be used.

**Update:** The feature request for this is viewable [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158736319), to increase visibility on this, hit the ☆ at the top of the page.

#### Relevant Questions:

- [OAuth consent screen - ability to remove application logo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168008/1992004) [Obsolete]

Comment: Good, one more reason to feel frustrated during the pandemic :) And one more issue tracker to vent on ;)

Comment: Using DELETE method worked for a while but not anymore (404 error) https://stackoverflow.com/a/63858175/488666 Sad :-(

Comment: There's now a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185141979. Please, upvote it there, hopefully, it will get more attention than a feature request, 'cause honestly, it IS a bug!

Comment: @Dmitry This isn't a bug, it's currently intended behaviour. [This comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158736319#comment3) on [this feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158736319) from a Googler confirms this - *"This feature request is already forward to the Cloud UI product team and they are working on it. However, there is no ETA atthis time."* - it's more important to star *this* issue so Google sees that it's highly requested and bumps up the priority.

Answer (score 0):

May 2021 - It is still possible to completely delete the consent screen (and thus allowing to create it again). See my updated answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168008/1992004

Comment: The linked method didn't work for me but a modified version of it did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67770952/1317406