# How or where do i "open up a Cloud Console session"

Tags: google-oauth, google-cloud-console

This question is for one of the steps in the answer to this question:
[OAuth consent screen - ability to remove application logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989198/oauth-consent-screen-ability-to-remove-application-logo/57168008#57168008)

"Back on the site, open up a Cloud Console session (The terminal icon in the top menu bar) and paste the modified command, then run it."

I cannot find any terminal icon in the top menu bar or where to open a cloud console session. Can anyone provide a screenshot of what icon / option or better explanation of what Chris was talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the first (Cloud Shell) icon as shown here (`>_`) when browsing http://console.cloud.google.com

[image]

IIUC the answer is helping generate a `curl` command that you can paste into any shell. The answer uses Cloud Shell as it's available in the browser and cross-platform.