# OAuth consent screen verification required due to logo but unable to remove logo

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I added an application logo by mistake on the OAuth consent screen (URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent), and now it says my consent screen requires verification by Google, where as it wouldn't otherwise.

Is there any way to remove the application logo from the consent screen?

Same as [OAuth consent screen - ability to remove application logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989198/oauth-consent-screen-ability-to-remove-application-logo) but I don't have the reputation to create an answer. Hopefully this saves someone else some time.

Answer (score 1):

Created a new project explicitly for oauth credentials. Breaks some of the reporting but I no longer have to verify my oauth.

Added bonus: This method also allows you to have a published oauth and another oauth for dev using localhost. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456174/oauth-how-to-test-with-local-urls)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry, the link doesn't address the original question. The first paragraph fully answers the question. The second paragraph notes that the answer is useful for an entirely separate task. Edited answer for clarity.