# How can I reset OAuth consent screen?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, idp, google-cloud-console

I have followed instrucctions from [OAuth consent screen - ability to remove application logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989198/oauth-consent-screen-ability-to-remove-application-logo)

to remove logo.

But now, when I try to create an OAuth client Id I can´t because  the following message :

*"The brand that you're trying to edit has been deleted. Recreate your brand."*

I have tried to recreated brand, filling form of "Consent screeen" but I can´t. It is showing the error : "An error occurred while saving your app"

In developer console of chrome I read the message returned and I got this :

*{"error":{"code":5,"message":"The resource has been deleted.","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo","reason":"RESOURCE_DELETED","domain":"clientauthconfig.googleapis.com","metadata":{"resource_name":"["brand"]"}}]}}*

Now, the project it is in an inconsistent status and I can´t continue.

Any help would be aprreciated in order to reset the consent screen o create a new one

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only way is to create  a new project explicitly for oauth credentials. Also there is an [open feature request](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/158736319) to solve this issue. If you feel so you can **add +1 and leave a comment** as you are also expecting this feature to be default.

Comment: You need to do the 8'th step https://stackoverflow.com/a/67770952

Comment: no, step 8 is what leads to the error reported by the OP